# Speakers stops working when volume is turned up to 50% or more

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, lenovo-laptop, speakers

I have a Lenovo G400s laptop running Windows 7 Ultimate. Everything's perfect except my sound. The speakers work fine when I play any song and set the volume to 40%, but it ceases to work as soon as I turn up the volume to 50% or more. Even decreasing the volume down to 40% doesn't help to get it back to work. I would have to close and restart the application to get my sound back.

What is the problem: my speakers or my sound driver? How can I solve this?

Comment: It's always good to have updated drivers and firmwares, but I think the problem is physical.
Have you tried connecting external speakers?

Comment: When you say like that, I try to connect with headphone because I don't have external speaker. It work fine and I can increase it until 100% volume without any problem. As you said, it might physical problem. Do you know how to fix the speaker? Is there any cable that might lose for some reason or problem with board? Do you know how. Sorry if my English not so well/good to read.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a physical problem, I don't think you can do much.
You can try disassemble the speakers (maybe this [link](http://www.ehow.com/how_4970088_replace-speakers-laptop.html) can help you with some instructions) from the laptop and see if their connectors are damaged.
If you want to test them first before replacing them, it might be a bit of a problem if you're no good enough dealing with electronics.

If you're not too keen dealing with hardware, than I'd suggest you turn to a PC technician.